# Determining whether a series is convergent or not

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am having trouble with this problem:

Let $a_n$ be sequence of positive terms with $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\lt \frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}.$$
Then is the series $\sum a_n$ convergent?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you use that to relate $a_n$ to $a_1$ somehow?

Comment: @Ester: it is not clear whether you are asking about the convergence of $\{a_n\}$ or $\sum a_n$.

Comment: I answered the question thinking he meant convergence of the sequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that
$$
a_n=a_1\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\le a_1\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k^2}{(k+1)^2}=\frac{a_1}{n^2},
$$
and as the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges so does the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, as a consequence of the comparison test.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Daniel Fischer's comment let 
$$v_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$$
so we have
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<\frac{v_{n+1}}{v_n}\iff \frac{a_{n+1}}{v_{n+1}}<\frac{a_{n}}{v_{n}}$$
hence the sequence $\left(\frac{a_{n}}{v_{n}}\right)$ is decreasing and then
$$ \frac{a_{n}}{v_{n}}<\frac{a_{1}}{v_{1}}=C\iff a_n<C v_n$$
and since the series $\displaystyle\sum_n v_n$ is convergent then the series $\displaystyle\sum_n a_n$ is also convergent by comparison.

Comment: Daniel's made lights on many problems in this site. +1

Answer (score 2):

Or [Gauss's Test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssTest.html)

$$
\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}} > \frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2} = 1 + \frac{\color{red}2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2},
$$
and $\color{red}2>1$ so we have convergence.

Comment: :Isn't the Gauss' Test states equality rather than inequality?

Comment: Perhaps you can prove as a corollary the inequality version.